# How to optimally use multi-threading with multi-processing in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, gil

I've created a processor class in Python that needs to execute multiple executables parallelly (or serially). Processor and Executable classes may look as follows:

```
Class Processor(object):
    executables: list() # list of Executable objects
    should_execute_in_parallel: bool
    attr1: object
    attr2: object

    def process():
        # Pre-processing
        # Execute all executables serailly/parallely based on self.should_execute_in_parallel
        # Post-processing
    

Class Executable(object):
    cmd: str  # command string to execute
    attr1: object
    attr2: object
```

I have created  an Executor class which takes an executable and executes it

```
class Executor(object):
    def __init__(self, executable):
        self.executable = executable
        # This is to demonstrate that Executor object is stateful
        self.executable_id = self._get_executable_id(self.executable)

    def execute():
        # Pre-processing (I/O bound, depends on self)
        # Launch separate process for self.executable & monitor (I/O during each monitoring phase)
        # Post-processing (I/O bound, depends on self)
```

I'm looking to parallelize Executor.execute() in Processor.process(). Since a new Python process is spawned by each Executor.execute() call, multi-processing at the Processor level may be overkill. Hence, I'm thinking of using multiple threads for each Executor object which in-turn will spawn a new process for respective executable and keep on monitoring it.

Note: The process launched by Executor.execute() needs to be monitored periodically by the Executor object, for which I'm using python alarm. I/O happens during each monitoring phase.

1. Is there a recommended/optimal way in python to combine multi-threading with multi-processing (like above)?
2. As long as Executor.execute() is not CPU bound (excluding the spawned process), can there be any GIL issues?
3. Would it be easier to achieve parallelism here, if Executor objects were stateless?
4. Is there any better way to solve this use-case?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be much happier using a single process and single thread and the [subprocess module from python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). If all your code is doing is spawning other programs just do so in a non-blocking fashion.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your questions, might I offer the following answers, hoping that they help!

*1. Is there a recommended/optimal way in python to combine multi-threading with multi-processing (like above)?*

If you're calling different processes in the system, consider using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) which in turn can be called from a variety of threads managed by a [thread pool](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html). If you genuinely need processes independent of the GIL you're subject to, consider hiving out to [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) or looking at whether you should be using a concurrent/distributed task scheduler like Dask.

*2. As long as Executor.execute() is not CPU bound (excluding the spawned process), can there be any GIL issues?*

There will always be some issues with the GIL unless you distribute away from the python interpreter you're running in, which can be achieved with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) as mentioned above. When running your OS process out of that object the current threads you're using will still interact with the GIL, from my understanding (I'm sure someone can explain this way better than I have...)

*3. Would it be easier to achieve parallelism here, if Executor objects were stateless?*

They're always going to be stateful in some sense unless you detach them from the initial process they've been initiated from. I think if you're running subprocesses in the OS, you can multithread multiple executors and let them run.

*4. Is there any better way to solve this use-case?*

[I wonder if you'd find the concurrent.futures package interesting](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=threadpool)

I really hope this helps, doubtless as this is an early answer for me I could do with refining my explanations.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hey Jim, thanks for the detailed answer. It helped me better understand the theory here and decide how to proceed with my use-case.